# how do I create an array from a while loop and send array to another class when a button is clicked?

Tags: java, android

how do I create an array from a while loop and send array to another class when a button is clicked?

while loop is under populateListViewTask, I need to make the item id an array and then pass the ids when a button is clicked

```
e.g 
reOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityMyAccountOrdersView.this, ActivityStep10ListCart.class);
                    intent.putExtra("selectedoutlet",extras.getString("orderOutlet2"));
startActivity(intent);
     }
});



private class populateListViewTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
      protected void onPostExecute(String params) {
      try {
                Integer totalItems = 0;
                JSONObject jsonOrderObject = new JSONObject(order);
                Iterator<String> loop = jsonOrderObject.keys();
                 while (loop.hasNext()) {
                    String key = loop.next();               

                    try {
                        String orderItems = jsonOrderObject.get(key).toString();

                        JSONObject orderItemsObj = new JSONObject(orderItems);

                        String item_id = orderItemsObj.getString("id");
 } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // Something went wrong!
                    }





                }
}
      }

}
```

Comment: Is this question Android specific?

Comment: @mlewandowski yes am working on android app and am stuck.

Comment: @mlewandowski i need to pass array of the ids to ActivityStep10ListCart from ActivityMyAccountOrdersView when a button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Declare globally

```
String[] itemIds = null;
```

Use a list to consolidate all items and then convert it to an array

```
        List<String> all_items = new ArrayList<>();
        while (loop.hasNext()) {
            String key = loop.next();

            try {
                String orderItems = jsonOrderObject.get(key).toString();

                JSONObject orderItemsObj = new JSONObject(orderItems);

                String item_id = orderItemsObj.getString("id");
                all_items.add(item_id);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // Something went wrong!
            }

        }

        itemIds = all_items.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Use this itemIds array to put as extras in your intent.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityMyAccountOrdersView.this,
            ActivityStep10ListCart.class);
    intent.putExtra("selectedoutlet", extras.getString("orderOutlet2"));
    intent.putExtra("itemids", itemIds);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

At the receiving end get these ids using

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  String[] itemIds = intent.getStringArrayExtra("itemids");
```

Hope this helps.

Please note this code might not be compilable, i wrote it to give you some idea only.